# Switching users in Fabric always prompt for a password

Tags: python, fabric

I've tried many ways to switch users to do a restore backup for `postgres` using `fabric`.

This is my current code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
from fabric.api import run, env, settings, hosts, execute
from fabric.operations import get

...

@hosts(['127.0.0.1'])
def restore_localdb(dump_file):
    with settings(user="postgres"):
        run('dropdb potato')
        run('createdb -E UTF8 -O potato potato')

    run('psql -U potato -h localhost potato -W < %s' % dump_file)


def local_clone():
    dump_file = execute(backupdb)
    execute(restore_localdb, dump_file)
```

I cannot understand the prompt for `potato` password on `dropdb potato` sentence, when It is supposed that the system have been switched to `postgres` user.

I've tried with `sudo`, but the two sentences inside the switch in `restore_localdb` must be executed as `postgres`.

I've tried also with `env.user` and nothing. Also with:

```
sudo('dropdb potato', user='postgres')
```

with same result.

`local` command is not useful for me because I need to switch between users and I can't do it with `local`.

I only want to emulate these bash commands:

```
> sudo su - postgres
# I'll write the password for root
> dropdb potato
# The database is finally dropped without any more prompts
```

Any idea?

Comment: fabric still has to connect to ssh to postgres@127.0.0.1. One workaround could be adding an ssh pkey to postgre's `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. As soon as you're able to do `ssh postgres@127.0.0.1` without a prompt it should be done.

Comment: Working !! Thank you !!